# How to enable zts and re-compile php on ubuntu18.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, zts

I'm not native, sorry my bad grammar.

I'm using PHP 7.3.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to enable `ZTS` and recompile PHP. I have tried several times but didn't work.

May you guide me?

I tried https://www.rapidspike.com/blog/php7-pthreads/

and in step-2,

I got this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.3.8-zts  
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3.8-zts'  
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3.8-zts'  
E: Unable to locate package php7.3.8-zts-common  
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3.8-zts-common'  
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3.8-zts-common'    
E: Unable to locate package php7.3.8-zts-xml  
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3.8-zts-xml'  
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3.8-zts-xml'   
E: Unable to locate package php7.3.8-zts-dev  
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3.8-zts-dev'  
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3.8-zts-dev'
```

Then I used this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

but I got the same error again.

Comment: Have you thought of trying to use Docker as they have pre-built images for most versions and configurations.

Comment: what is your installation command?